# Why does const std::pair<K,V>& in range-based for loop on std::map not work?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdmap

When accessing the elements of a `std::map` via `const auto& entry` in a **range-based for loop** I get a reference to the actual data in the map. Using `const std::pair<K,V>&` on the other hand does **not give a reference to the data in the `std::map`**

Consider this example *(compiled with gcc 7.4, -std=c++14)*

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> my_map {{"foo", 42}};
    for(const auto& entry : my_map)
        std::cout << entry.first << ' ' << entry.second << ' ' << &(entry.second) << std::endl;
    for(const std::pair<std::string, int>& entry : my_map)
        std::cout << entry.first << ' ' << entry.second << ' ' << &(entry.second) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo 42 0x11a7eb0
foo 42 0x7ffec118cfc0
```

I am aware that the `std::map` value_type is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. But I don't really understand what is happening in the case of the second range-based loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map<K, V>::value_type` is `std::pair<const K, V>`, not `std::pair<K, V>` (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map))

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::map<std::string, int> my_map {{"foo", 42}};
    for(const auto& entry : my_map)
        std::cout << entry.first << ' ' << entry.second << ' ' << &(entry.second) << std::endl;
    for(const std::pair<std::string, int>& entry : my_map)
        std::cout << entry.first << ' ' << entry.second << ' ' << &(entry.second) << std::endl;
    for(const std::pair<const std::string, int>& entry : my_map)
        std::cout << entry.first << ' ' << entry.second << ' ' << &(entry.second) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Example output](https://godbolt.org/z/MEx8se):

```
foo 42 0x2065eb0
foo 42 0x7ffc2d536070
foo 42 0x2065eb0
```

Your second loop works because it's creating a temporary `std::pair<std::string, int>` and binding it to your reference ([explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary)). You can see it fail if you try to use a non-const reference instead (since it can't bind to a temporary):

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type '`std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&`' from expression of type '`std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>`'

Comment: Makes sense. Did not consider that a temporary object gets created. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the types inside the `std::map` are `std::pair<const Key, T>`, not `std::pair<Key, T>`. This means that when we iterate over the map and pull out `const std::pair<Key, T>&`s, we can't get a reference to the element, but something else is happening. This something else is *lifetime extension.* This loop:

```
for(const std::pair<std::string, int>& entry : my_map) {
    ...
}
```

Is roughly equivalent to this loop:

```
for(const std::pair<std::string, int> entry : my_map) {
    ...
}
```

So you're actually getting a copy of every entry in the map.